# С# char convert.toint32.... В чем проблема конвертирования?

Tags: c#, int

Делаю игру быки и коровы. Не понимаю откуда проблема. При преобразовании строки или масива чаров, в масиве чисел появляються другие значения. Если 1 = 49, 2 = 50, 3 = 51 и тд. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

[image: Часть кода]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код надо текстом вставлять. Вы получаете код символа. `int digit = c - '0'` где `digit` - число, а `c` - символ. Еще зря массив символов создаете, строку можно так же в цикле итерировать как и массив символов, ну а если очень надо, то `char[] chars = text.ToCharArray()` где `text` - `string`, но в вашем случае отдельный массив вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы прям в прямом смысле преобразуете char в int. char это символ, а его преобразование в числовой тип данных будет выдавать вам ИНДЕКС СИМВОЛА. char   имеет диапазон от 0 до 65535. Это можно понять по тому, что сам тип данных char занимает в памяти 16 бит, соответственно, всего его значения кодируются в 16-битной кодировке. Ваши соответствующие числа это соответствующие индексы этих цифр в [таблице ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Для вашего преобразования попробуйте использовать int.Parse или [явное преобразование char в int](https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/convert-char-to-int-csharp/)

Comment: _char имеет диапазон от 1 до 255_ - от 0 до 65535. _таблице ASCII_ - частный случай, кодировка символов в C# действительно совпадаетс с ASCII в определённом диапазоне, но на самом деле это юникод, UTF-16.

Comment: @aepot, да, я перечитал, вы правы. char кодируется в 16-битной кодировке, т.е. диапазон и вправду от 0 до 65535.

Comment: Исправьте ответ в таком случае

Answer (score 0):

Используй `Int32.Parse()`
там есть несколько перегрузок смотри на https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-7.0

Но т.к. это консольный ввод то нет гарантии что пользователь будет вводить исключительно числа.
Можно использовать `TryParse()`

Comment: `Int32.Parse()` никак не распарсит `char`.